# How do I avoid build errors when I include SQLCipher pod in Swift project?

Tags: cocoapods, sqlcipher, sqlite.swift

I am using [sqlite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)

When I include this in my pod file:

```
  pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher', '~> 0.12.2'
```

Is SQLCipher still compatible with SQLite.swift?
Do I need additional pod statements to import SQLCipher and SQLite or just this one line?

XCode reports error when I build that look like this:

> /Pods/SQLCipher/sqlite3.h:6907:10: Redefinition of 'sqlite3_index_orderby'
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:6758:10: Previous definition is here
> Pods/SQLite.swift/Sources/SQLiteObjc/include/SQLiteObjc.h:26:9: While building module 'SQLite3' imported from /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpeechCollector-btdxklvmapneuigwvexrhccrhodq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLite.swift/SQLite.framework/Headers/SQLiteObjc.h:26:
> /:2:9: In file included from :2:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:10: In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h:20:

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue on our project, and we couldn't update to the next Xcode until this was solved.

The repo SQLite.swift looks abandoned, but among the pull requests there's [this one](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/pull/1024) that resolved the issue for our project.

What we did is download the repo and added it as a local dependency (we are using Cocoapods), then we added the changes that appear in that PR.
In file `SQLiteObjc.h`, we changed from

```
@import Foundation;
#if defined(SQLITE_SWIFT_STANDALONE)
@import sqlite3;
#else
@import SQLite3;
#endif
```

to

```
@import Foundation;
#if defined(SQLITE_SWIFT_STANDALONE)
@import sqlite3;

#elif defined(SQLITE_SWIFT_SQLCIPHER)
@import SQLCipher;

#else
@import SQLite3;
#endif
```

Hope this helps to you also.